# Compact way to declare sequential javascript variables?

Tags: javascript

Existing code:

```
var e1; 
var e2; 
var e3;
var e4;
var e5;
var e6;
var e7;
```

Is there a way to declare the variables that is like "var e1 to var e50" ?
I have to make a bunch of variables for my program and it is tiresome to have to type each one.

Thanks

Comment: Seems like that is a bad idea....

Comment: `var e = [];` ?

Comment: you could take an array for sequential data

Comment: `var vars = { e1: '', e2: '', ...}`. use `vars.e1`, etc.

Comment: Why do you need so many variables?

Answer (score 1):

JS can't loop through variable creation.

You probably just want to use an array instead:

`var myThings = [];`

to access a value:

`myThings[0]`

You can also loop through this if you need to.

Answer (score 1):

Regardless of whether it's a good idea or not, the comma operator lets you declare multiple variables without repeating 'var':

```
var e1, e2, e3;
```

you can format with whitespace:

```
var e1,
    e2,
    e3;
```

Answer (score 0):

> tiresome to have to type each one

Then you need an [`Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array), but you must count from `0` to your `length - 1` in order to use it.

This

```
var e = ["e1", "e2", "e3", "e4", "e5", "e6", "e7"];
```

is the same as this

```
var e = [];
e[0] = "e1";
e[1] = "e2";
e[2] = "e3";
e[3] = "e4";
e[4] = "e5";
e[5] = "e6";
e[6] = "e7";
```